# If statement looping twice

Tags: wordpress, if-statement, advanced-custom-fields

Im trying to get it so if the field is set show the top half else show a placement. It works to some degree in that fact it shows the empty, but its showing it twice and i cant seem to figure out why

```
<?php if( have_rows('attach_files_multiple') ): while ( have_rows('attach_files_multiple') ) : the_row(); ?>  

                        <?php if( get_row_layout() == 'neck' ) : ?>
                        <div class="media">
                            <div class="media-left media-middle">
                            <!-- Image Start -->
                                <?php $image = get_sub_field('preview_prop_neck');
                                if( !empty($image) ): ?>
                                    <img class="media-object" width="100px" src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            <!-- Image End -->
                            </div>

                            <div class="media-body">
                                <?php $file = get_sub_field('prop_file_neck'); ?>
                                <h4 class="media-heading">
                                    Neck Piece 
                                    <a href="<?php echo $file['url']; ?>" class="pull-right btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Download</a>
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <?php elseif ( !empty(get_row_layout('neck')) ) : ?>
                            <div class="overlay"><h3>Helmet - No File Found</h3></div>
                            <div class="media">
                            <div class="media-left media-middle">
                            <!-- Image Start -->
                                <img class="media-object" width="100px" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/pdo.png">
                            <!-- Image End -->
                            </div>
                            <div class="media-body">
                                <h4 class="media-heading">
                                    Neck Piece 
                                    <a href="#" class="pull-right btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Download</a>
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php endwhile; ?> <!-- End while ( have_rows( ) -->
                        <?php endif; ?> <!-- End if( have_rows ) ?> -->
```

Answer (score 0):

```
                    <?php if( get_row_layout() == 'neck' ) : ?>
```

Here you are saying "if neck row layout exists, output the layout below".

```
                <?php elseif ( !empty(get_row_layout('neck')) ) : ?>
```

Here you are basically saying "if neck row layout is not empty, output the layout below". So it's outputting twice because I'm assuming you have a neck row.